# outputting numbers from given file in decreasing order without built in functions

Tags: python, file, list, min

I have to:

1. ask user to input file
2. check that the file exists
3. store numbers (from file) in a list
4. find length of the list
5. and sort in decreasing order without built in functions

Here's what I have so far:

```
def main():
    try:        
        file=open(input (str("Please enter the name of the file you wish to open:" )),"r")
        A= file.readlines()
        print (A)
        file.close

        n=len(str(A))
        print (n)

        new_list=[]
        for i in range (n):
            for j in range (n-i):
                if A(j-1) < A(j):
                    swap (A(j), A(j-1))
    except IOError as e:
        print("({})".format(e))
```

I don't know what to print for after the swap.
I get error ("File "C:/Python33/project.py", line 15, in main
    if A(j-1) < A(j):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable")

What should I do?

Comment: To access elements of a list you use `[]` not `()` - but what's `swap`? (looks like you've pretty much pasted some pseudo-code)

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call a `list` as a function rather than indexing it

```
if A(j-1) < A(j):
    swap (A(j), A(j-1))
```

should actually be

```
if A[j-1] < A[j]:
    swap (A[j], A[j-1])
```

To know how to index a list, please read through this tutorial [3.1.3 Lists](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/lists.html)

Yo know more about Python functions read [4.6 Defining Functions](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html)

Comment: I figured that was my mistake as well but when I index it I get error ("File "C:/Python33/project.py", line 15, in main
    if A[n-1] < A[n]:
IndexError: list index out of range")